# POST-request with multipart/form-data from ExtJS form to .Net5 controller gets responseText empty

Tags: json, extjs, controller

I have a form in ExtJS:

```
{
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [{        
            xtype: 'filefield',
            name: 'azezFile'  
        }],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Load',
            handler: function() {
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();      
                if(form.isValid()) { 
                    form.submit({
                        url: uploadApiPath,   
                        success: function(fp, o) {
                           // Never goes here
}
});
...
```

It sends file to a controller (.Net5):

```
namespace KROSS_Core.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class UploadController : ControllerBase
    {                    
        // POST: api/Upload
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {
            //AzezUploadFile(this.HttpContext);
            return Ok(new { success = true });
            //return Ok(LoadFileToBase(this.HttpContext));
            //return BadRequest(new { success = false, message = "Wrong answer" });
        }
```

Controller getting request and responses normally, but I got an exception in ext-all-debug.js:

> Unhandled exception at line 6092, column 17 in
> https : // localhost:44364/Website/Scripts/ext.js/ext-all-debug.js
> 0x800a139e - Error JavaScript: Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to
> decode an invalid JSON String:

And response.responseText is empty in debugger. After I close that exception, the browser (IE11) asks me to save or open that json file.
Firefox shows another error in console:

```
"You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <pre>{\"success\":true}</pre>"
```

, but it was set [Produces("application/json")] in controller...

Google Chrome log: `"You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"success":true}</pre>"`

What is the problem and how to make it working? The same controller method loaded without sending multipart form-data goes normally and ExtJS works with response JSON.

Comment: have you tried using type Object and plain return instead using IActionResult and Ok ?

Comment: {\" <-- Your JSON is not correct, have escape symbols (backslasch) in your JSON.

Comment: @FabioBarros I tried it first of all and now tried again, but the result is the same - empty reponseText

Comment: @ArthurRubens as you can see, I don't serialize it by myself, .Net5 does it, so it makes really correct JSON, I always get correct JSON result doing the same request but without sending file in form-data

Comment: it appears to be escaping double quotes in the response when the object is passed to json, maybe you could try to change the response to string and return plain text "{ 'success' = false}"

Comment: @FabioBarros thank you for trying to help, but it also doesn't work for some reason.. I changed the method from ExtJS form submit to own uploadFile method with XMLHttpRequest and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to fix it in ExtJS, but I used another method of uploading a file to a server (same controller), and it works perfect:

```
function uploadFile(file, url, success, failure) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    formData.append('file', file);

    request.onload = function (response) {
        var jsonResult = JSON.parse(response.target.responseText);

        if (jsonResult.exception || jsonResult.error) {
            failure(jsonResult);
        }
        else {
            success(jsonResult);
        }
    };

    request.open("POST", url);
    request.send(formData);
}
```

And use it like

```
uploadFile(form.down('[name=fileInnputName]').extractFileInput().files[0], uploadApiPath, function() { }, function() { });
```